# Internet Explorer's back button and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I've got an asp.net page that uses dynamically populated DropDownLists and OnSelectedIndexChanged events.  A few days ago I found a defect where hitting the back button would load the previous page from the browser's cache, so the DropDownList would already have a selected index (hence the OnSelectedIndexChanged event would not fire properly as it didn't have the default selected index).  I understood the issue and googled around.  It's a well known issue that doesn't have an easy solution because of how the browser interacts with the page.  After a bit of thought, I went with a trivial javascript solution to reset the ddls:

```
        var gvTable = document.getElementById("foo");
        if (gvTable != null)
        {
            var actionDDls = gvTable.getElementsByTagName("select");
            for (var i in actionDDls) {
                actionDDls[i].value = 0;
            }
        }
```

This worked well and I was happy.  Until I tested it in IE.  In IE, it appears to run the script, THEN load the cached values of the DDL.  That is, I observe the DDL snapping back to the 0 index, and then suddenly dropping down to the previously selected value.

I'm sort of at a loss here, I typically debug in firebug, but this works perfectly in firefox and chrome.  Any suggestions? Thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to look at history points feature in .NET 3.5? http://www.pin5i.com/showtopic-16198.html.  This may help the current issue through a custom state management feature.

HTH.

Comment: That's a lot to digest on my schedule, but if that's the way life goes, that's how it goes sometimes.  Thanks for the link!